# RegEx...Trying to replace pattern in Html file

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want to replace the following pattern in an html file

```
 <BR>1696.54</TD>
```

to

```
<TD>1696.54</TD>
```

I am using the RegEx.Replace code

```
 result = Regex.Replace(html, "<BR>\d</TD>", "<TD>$1</TD>")
```

but I am doing something incorrectly as nothing happens.

Any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need capture a group using parentheses and change :

```
`\d`
```

to

```
`\d*\.\d*`
```

try this :

```
result = Regex.Replace(html, "<BR>(\d*\.\d*)</TD>", "<TD>$1</TD>")
```